# How to delete or track the sign-in information on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, password, ipados

I have used a couple of Adobe apps on my iPad. Following the first time I logged in to my account, it just remembers the details. I’m not sure if it remembers the password as well since they were just randomly used email/usernames and I was redirected to the verification page.

Similarly, I logged in to Gmail and now it remembers my google account details which I suppose makes sense as I can go to “Manage account settings” and set things.

How do I delete the information from Adobe cloud? Where exactly and how does Apple store these information? I do not have anything in the Autofill section or Password Manager (Keychain/Website and App passwords).

Answer (score 2):

Third party apps can securely store and retrieve the login session information in the iPad's keychain (which unlike macOS keychain is not user accessible). The apps often does that so that it makes it seamless for users to log into other app(s) from the same developer (Both Google and Adobe publish multiple apps on the App Store).

You can take either one of the approaches (as made available by the developer of the app) to disassociate iPad from your account or log out from iPad:

1. Login to manage your account using a desktop web browser (such as for Google or Adobe), access the logged in devices and disassociate the device.
2. Get access to user account management within one of the apps on iPad and exercise the option to remove your account from log out from it.

An app developer would generally provide either one or both the options for users.